# convert a collection of char into string without the comma and square brackets

Tags: java, string, collections

I want to print a string that is converted from a collection of characters. But I want to eliminate the commas (,) and square brackets([]) from the printing string.

```
List<Character> word_to_show = new ArrayList<Character>(); 
for(char ch:jumbled_word.toCharArray()){ 
 word_to_show.add(ch); 
} 
Collections.shuffle(word_to_show); 
for (Object ch: word_to_show) 
  System.out.print((Character) ch ); 
System.out.println(); 
send_to_timer = word_to_show.toString();
```

I have come to this. It works but prints the string as, say for eg, `[a, b, c]`

Comment: And what have you tried so far? In general, people here want to **help** when you are stuck; but most people refuse to do all the work for you.

Comment: I have come to this. It works but prints the string as, say for eg, [a, b, c]

Comment: When you are asked to provide more details - please update your question. Never put code into comments.

Comment: ok.. the string converted from collection prints as, [a,b,c,d]. But I want to print it as abcd

Comment: You received several answers by now; please consider "accepting" one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace()`

```
string.replace(",","").replace("[","").replace("]","")
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/Jfxesm)

Comment: why don't you vote or accept answer if you find it useful. ?? @ArhatBaid

Answer (score 1):

If you have a real Collection containing characters, you can simply iterate that collection - and use a StringBuilder to append all those characters that you want to have in your final string; like:

```
StringBuilder validChars = new StringBuilder();
for (Character chr : yourCollection) {
  if (chr != ' ' && chr != ',') {
     validChars.append(chr);
  }
}
```

First turning all characters into a string, then use replace() to create a new string with less characters seems a bit inefficient.